# Spring RESTful web service using only XML config

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I've been using only XML configuration to make MVC web applications (no annotation).

Now I want to make a RESTful web service with Spring but I could not find any tutorial that doesn't use annotation.

Is there a way to build a RESTful web service with only XML configuration ?
Or do I HAVE TO use annotation ?

For example, you can deploy an MVC pattern web application using only XML configuration like below.

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.ParameterMethodNameResolver" id="springParameterMethodNameResolver">
    <property name="paramName" value="action"/>
   </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
       <map>
            <entry key="/test.do" >
                <ref bean="testController"  />
            </entry>
            <entry key="/rest/test">
                <ref bean="testRESTController"/>
            </entry>
        </map>

    </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- My Beans -->
   <bean id="testMethodNameResolver" class="com.rhcloud.riennestmauvais.spring.test.TestMethodNameResolver">
   </bean>

   <!-- Test -->
   <bean class="com.rhcloud.riennestmauvais.spring.test.TestController" id="testController">
        <property name="delegate" ref="testDelegate"/>
        <property name="methodNameResolver" ref="testMethodNameResolver"></property>
        <!-- <property name="methodNameResolver" ref="springParameterMethodNameResolver"></property> -->
   </bean>
   <bean class="com.rhcloud.riennestmauvais.spring.test.TestDelegate" id="testDelegate">
   </bean>
```

However, I hit a wall when I was trying to map a method for URL for example
HTTP method : `POST`, URL : `/student/1/Adam` - so that I could add a student.
The URL format would be like this: `/[resource]/[id]/[name]`

I could map `/student/1/Adam` to a controller by putting a pattern in the entry key like:

```
<entry key="/student/regex-to-allow-number/regex-to-allow-string">
```

But how should I parse the URI within my controller ?

I could parse the URI by using `String.split()` or something like that but I'm wondering if there isn't already some solution to this so that I could avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: *Why* do you want to use XML and not annotations?

Comment: Well, I am used to using XML but if there is no way I can make a RESTful web service this way, I can just use annotation. I'm just a little obsessed with XML configuration :)

Comment: Annotation-based configuration is usually preferable to XML; it's type-safe and generally keeps information in one spot (the class) rather than spreading it out in multiple places. This sounds like a case where a method-level `@RequestMapping` will be massively easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Ah yes I think so too. But "massively easier" would imply it is possible ?

Comment: Hello Ascendant, I'm looking for projects that work only with XML, can you send me the source code of a MVC web app please ?

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
        
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.apmc.rest" />
   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   
    </beans>
```

This is rest-servlet.xml. This file must be configure in web.xml by using DispatcherServlet class

```html
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Above code write in web.xml
load-on-startup 1 give for spring-security.xml and spring-config.xml

Comment: the question was how to use XML only configuration, and this answer assume to use annotations.