# Mapping Spring-WS to an endpoint, request xml and output xml

Tags: spring-ws

I would like to implement a Spring Web Service which accepts the call `notifySmsDeliveryReceipt` on our endpoint 
`http://xxx.xx.xx.x:8088/axis2/services/SmsNotificationService`. The content of the call will be like thw following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=‘http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/’ xmlns:v3=‘http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/common/v3_1’ xmlns:loc=‘http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/notification/v3_1/local’>
  <soapenv:Header>
    <v3:NotifySOAPHeader>
      <spId>600002</spId>
    </v3:NotifySOAPHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <loc:notifySmsDeliveryReceipt>
      <loc:correlator>123</loc:correlator>
      <loc:deliveryStatus>
        <address>tel:+86123</address>
        <deliveryStatus>DeliveredToTerminal</deliveryStatus>
      </loc:deliveryStatus>
    </loc:notifySmsDeliveryReceipt>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The operation `notifySmsDeliveryReceipt` should return the following:

I have set up a Spring WS project and started with an endpoint.

```
@Endpoint
public class SmsNotificationService {

    public void handleNotifyReceipt() {

    }
}
```

While I don't need someone who could write the code for me, I would really appreciate it if anyone could tell me how `handleNotifyReceipt()` should be annotated and what parameter it should receive. I also need help in configuring the service to listen on the given URL and redirect the operation to `handleNotifyReceipt()`. I would also be grateful if anyone could tell me how to return the XML that the caller expects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below links could help you...http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html

[Spring RESTful web service using only XML config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911137/spring-restful-web-service-using-only-xml-config)